# Why is a lifetime needed when implementing a trait on a reference type if the lifetime is otherwise unused, in Rust < 1.31?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm implementing a trait for a reference type using a Rust older than 1.31. **Why does Rust want an explicit lifetime when I tell it what reference type I'm implementing the trait for?**

Here's a simple example. A struct `Inches`, an implementation of the
`Add` trait for `&Inches`, and a function that uses that implementation.

#### Initial example

[(Rust playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f7681a92c690b9452cab7590f8540462)

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Inches(i32);

// this would work: impl<'b> Add for &'b Inches
impl Add for &Inches {
    type Output = Inches;

    fn add(self, other: &Inches) -> Inches {
        let &Inches(x) = self;
        let &Inches(y) = other;

        Inches(x + y)
    }
}

// lifetime specifier needed here because otherwise 
// `total = hilt + blade` doesn't know whether `total` should live
// as long as `hilt`, or as long as `blade`.
fn add_inches<'a>(hilt: &'a Inches, blade: &'a Inches) {
    let total = hilt + blade;
    let Inches(t) = total;
    println!("length {}", t);
}

fn main() {
    let hilt = Inches(10);
    let blade = Inches(20);

    add_inches(&hilt, &blade);
}
```

Compilation fails with the following error:

```
error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
    impl Add for &Inches {
                 ^~~~~~~
```

#### I add the missing lifetime specifier (still doesn't compile)

```
// was: impl Add for &Inches {
impl Add for &'b Inches {
    ...
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error: use of undeclared lifetime name `'b` [E0261]
    impl Add for &'b Inches {
```

#### I declare the lifetime on the `impl` (now it compiles)

[(Rust playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=bd67f0bbc30977eb86f3523fc1346cf6)

```
// was: impl Add for &'b Inches {
impl<'b> Add for &'b Inches {
    ...
}
```

This, finally, compiles correctly.

#### My question

> Why is `&Inches` in `impl Add for &Inches` considered to lack a
>   lifetime specifier? What problem is solved by telling the compiler
>   that this Add method is for `&Inches` with some unspecified non-static
>   lifetime `'b`, and then never referring to that lifetime anywhere
>   else?

Comment: The lifetime of 'b is supplied (at compile-time of course) as 'a in the + operation, allowing the compiler to enforce/ensure the lifetime requirements of 'b out to 'a, and then out to the variables in main, right?  So, 'b is not unused, per se, it is an expression of a requirement that callers (transitively) must honor.

Comment: Your question already says what version it applies to: *I'm implementing a trait for a reference type **using Rust 1.30**.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Rust 1.31 and above

The reason is simple: it wasn't implemented until Rust 1.31.

Now, the initial example compiles, and you can write `impl Add for &Inches` instead of `impl<'b> Add for &'b Inches`. This is because 1.31.0 [stabilized new lifetime elision rules](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1310-2018-12-06).

## Before Rust 1.31

If you look at the [RFC for lifetime elision](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/704f0060176418659698eb63642e2071b109e029/active/0000-lifetime-elision.md) you can see that your use case should be covered:

```
impl Reader for BufReader { ... }                       // elided
impl<'a> Reader for BufReader<'a> { .. }                // expanded
```

However, I tried in the playground and [it doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f318afaf11baef16d338821d1e359b1e). The reason is that [it's not implemented yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15872).

I grepped Rust's source code for such cases, but there are suprisingly few of them. I could only find this series of implementations for `Add` on native types:

```
impl Add<u8> for u8
impl<'a> Add<u8> for &'a u8
impl<'a> Add<&'a u8> for u8
impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'a u8> for &'b u8
```

As you can see the lifetimes are all explicit here; no elision happens.

For your specific problem, I believe you'll have to stick with explicit lifetimes until the RFC implementation is done!

Comment: I think the lifetime, even when elided by elision rules, is still conceptually present and must be supplied by and honored by callers, no?

Comment: Lifetimes are still totally present. Elision rules indicate how the compiler can resolve missing lifetimes at compile-time, avoiding you to write "obvious", boilerplate annotations. Yes, they must be honored by callers, but in turn, those callers can benefit from elision themselves in their relevant part of the code.

Comment: Right. So one thing the OP is asking about is the apparent `unspecified ... 'b`, and my point is that it is not unspecified, that in some sense callers specify it by passing it in (effectively at compile time, and also transitively by callers of callers) and that this is true independent of (textual) elision working or not.  Of course, I may have misunderstood the OP...

Comment: Thank you @ErikEidt and mdup for reading and answering my question so carefully. Your answers "there must always be a lifetime, either explicit or deduced" (Erik) + "the compiler can't infer this one yet" (mdup), together answer both parts of my question 'why add a lifetime at all, and why can't I elide it'. Thank you both.

Comment: And special thanks for adding the link to the RFC and the issue. Pointing new people to primary sources and fora is invaluable for teaching people where to research answers, but also for drawing people into communities.